# Memory issues with Android app images

Tags: android, image, performance, android-studio, memory

I am having some memory issues with my android app, on startup it already has allocated 50+ MB depending on the occasion according to Android Studio's Memory tracking tool.

The tracking tool reports that a huge part of that is because of my background image and my 5 ImageButtons.

I can't understand why though, since my images are:

**background:** 184 kb  and becomes 40 MB

**imageButtons:** 10kb each ( 5 of them) and they become 7MB and 3MB

**How can they be taking up so many MBs if they are originally so small? And how to improve that?**

And this (attached) is what I see in the tracking tool

Background image
[image: background image]

5 ImageButtons
[image: 5 image buttons]

This is how I am loading the background image for example:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/backgroundImage"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    />
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice fair enough, updated

Answer (score 0):

You can estimate how many memory takes the uncompressed image by multiplying image width by height by 3 (for RGB) or by 4 (for RGB with alpha channel)

In my application i used OpenGL ETC1 comppression for backgrounds.

width x height | size in bytes

1024x1024 | 524388

2048x2048 | 2097252

I think this is the most effective way to store large images in device memory and quickly draw them.
I also did not see the Android devices that do not support ETC 1 compression.

This is not simple way, but most effective.

So try first to reduce the size and color depth of your images :)